# google maps and jquery tabs

Tags: javascript, php

i have problem in google maps and jquery tabs in the same page this is my problem link http://jsfiddle.net/3AsF7/
the second map doesnot show correctly, if any one faced this problem before please help me

```
     <body>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li style="outline:none; outline: 0;"> <a href="#tabs-1">Egypt contact</a>

        </li>
        <li style="outline:none; outline: 0;"> <a href="#tabs-2">Qatar contact</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <div id="google_img"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <div id="google_img2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function initialize() {
        var mapProp = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.037016, 31.216946),
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google_img"), mapProp);

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    function initialize2() {
        var mapProp = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(25.3207920, 51.5294840),
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google_img2"), mapProp);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize2);
</script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with tabs is that the panel where the map is loaded must be visible. Try to hide the panels with a `margin-top: -9999em` wait a few seconds and then apply the jQuery tab plugin that you are using.

The better way is that you create the map when the user goes to that tab.

Example: http://www.misionerosredentoristas.com/#!/casa/1

Do a click in the section "Cómo llegar" and you will see the delay to create the map.